# What hibernate do with unmapped column?

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose there is a class like that:

```
public class Entity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

And table with 3 columns: id, name and address.

```
CREATE TABLE entity (
    id NUMBER(9,0),
    name VARCHAR2(255),
    address VARCHAR2(1000),
```

Then en insert was performed:

```
INSERT INTO entity (id, name, address) VALUES (1, "a", "b")
```

Then we load and update hibernate entity:

```
Session session = ...
Entity entity = session.get(Entity.class, 1);
```

Then update name and save it again:

```
entity.setName("newName");
session.save(entity);
```

So what is address column value now - null or `b`? Does hibernate provide some stgrategies for such situations or I have to
add `address` field into entity and mark it as `@Column(updatable=false, insertable = false)`?

Comment: If it is not mapped, then it is being ignored. The address value will be the same "b".

Comment: @Cherry Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would put the following properties in persistence.xml(or where you have defined your hibernate properties)

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
```

Then you could see the queries executed by hibernate when server is run in debug mode with logged configured for debug.

If your entity is

```
public class Entity {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String secondName;
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

Then executing below HQL

```
SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.id = 121
```

would produce results similar to

```
SELECT entity0_.id        AS id1_63_, 
       entity0_.name      AS name6_63_, 
       entity0_.secondName AS secondName6_63_, 
FROM   yout_db.Entity entity0_ 
WHERE  entity0_.id = 121
```

You see that here `SELECT * FROM Entity` was not executed instead all the fields from the Class were fetched and added to the query. So if you have ignored any field from DB then it will NOT be taking part in Queries.

For Select-Update also same thing happens.

```
entity.setName("newName");
session.save(entity);
```

Below is formatted query if you would update an entity:

```
UPDATE your_db.Entity 
SET    name = ?
       secondName = ?
WHERE  id = ?
```

This query will be executed even if only one field is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate operates only with columns taken from entities, based on property name or described in annotation. So in your case 'address' value will be 'b'.

Comment: Could you please prove thus with dicunentation link?